# Problems With Aligning Adjacent Objects in CSS

Tags: css

I can't get the featured articles in the side bar to line up properly [(here)](http://www.glamourunderground.com/fitness/). I'm trying to get them to look more like the ones on [this site](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/beauty/article-1381264/Royal-Wedding-beauty-products-fit-Princess.html).

This is the CSS:

```
 #element2 {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 5px 0 0px 0px;
    color:#161514;
    font-family:helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #c7c7c7;
    width: 295px;
    height: 60%;
    }
img.element {
    width:305px;
    position:relative;
    right:auto;
    left:auto;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:130px;
    height:100px;
    min-height:100px;
    border:0;
    margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    }
p.element {
    position:relative;
    align:right;
    width:140px;
    height:100;
    min-height:100px;
    margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1pt;
    border:0;
    background:#c7c7c7;
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thank you,

Tara

PS: I'm using Chrome 10

Comment: Sorry the code area looks a bit messed up - I don't know why this is... [Fixed now thanks @pekka]

Comment: no problem. There are two "quote" buttons in the editor, the right-hand one (marked `{}`) is for code. It will only add four spaces before each line, but no `>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have messed too much with css.
delete `p.element` and `img.element` css rules and start styling again using this:

```
img.element {
    height: 100px;
    width: 130px;
   position: absolute;
}
p.element {
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    width: 140px;
}
```